# auto increment to incremented only 1 to 10

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

This is for my vb.net code when new record inserted patient id is checking for database value and incremented by next value ... code working fine to incremented only for 1 to 10. if record exceeds 10 value cannot be incremented.

```
Dim oleDBDR As OleDbDataReader
Dim oleDBCommand As New OleDbCommand
With oleDBCommand
.Connection = conn
.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblPatient ORDER BY PatientID DESC"
End With
oleDBDR = oleDBCommand.ExecuteReader
If oleDBDR.Read Then
txtPatientID.Text = Val(oleDBDR.Item(0)) + 1
End If
```

Comment: Let me know, which database you are using? what is the type of column where the value of auto increment variable stored? If you are using `mysql` then Auto increment primary key column is available their na? finally `Val("12") + 1` will gives 13 so no problem with this segment check your DB

Comment: @suji I was using msaccess 2003 db field name : patientID DataType: Text Field Size 255

Comment: See my answer, refer the Link. make the field as autoincrement

Comment: What problem are you having?

Answer (score 1):

Their is auto increment field available in `MS Access 2003` you can make use of this field to overcome this problem. This [Link](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/tables/autoinc.php) will guide you to achieve this